# How to call initMethod on the Bean after it is extracted using applicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext, spring-bean

Using spring boot application, I actually wanted to reinitialize the bean which extracted form applicaiton context. Something like below

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;


@GetMapping("endpoint")
public String getDetails(){
...

CommonClient client = context.getBeanOfType(CommonClient.class).get("QualifierIdentifier");

// now here i want to call init method that is similar to @Bean(initMethod = "initilize")

...

}
```

Comment: Does your class have initialize method if so, then directly you can call that method, are you seeing some issue?

Comment: Actually it hidden, CommonClient is the interface and its implementation class has the initilize method whose which is default access type. Therefore couldn't call it, you can assume CommonClient and its implementation class are present in jar tht i am using in my app

Comment: Is that method public/private or protected? Even I don't think Spring can call private methods. You can use Reflection to hack this.

Comment: Its default, Yes I can use reflection, but I guess it is not the best practice to use in the production code.